# Add all flat-attributes to product collection?

Tags: catalog, collection

How can I get a `catalog/product` collection with all attributes which are selected to be "used in product listing", i.e. are in the flat table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect(
          Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()
    );
```

This is for example used in  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection`.

Comment: Is this not equivalent with `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

Comment: no it is not. It get all the attributes which are marked as `used_in_product_listing`

Comment: Mark it as answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()
```

doesn't include all flat attributes. Still missing some attributes.
Use the flat reindexer Model instead to get exactly attributes that are in Flat table:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_flat_indexer')->getAttributeCodes();
```

Comment: Which attributes were not included in your case?